# zlib.h - no such file or directory, when building opencv

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, zlib

When I am building OpenCV, and running the make command, I get the following error:-

[image]

even though i have zlib installed in the path :- 
zlib: /usr/include/zlib.h /usr/share/man/man3/zlib.3.gz

Has anyone encountered this error before?